Unable to fetch neutron oslo notifications from rabbitMQ
We are trying to fetch oslo notifications related to:
1: VM related tasks like create, delete and update from nova.
2: port related tasks like create, delete and update from neutron.
This is being tested on a simple packstack allinone setup with openstack version Caracal. We are able to get notifications related to Nova but can't get any updates for port related events from neutron.
Config changes:
/etc/nova/nova.conf

[notifications]
notify_on_state_change=vm_state
default_level=INFO
notification_format=versioned
 
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
driver=messagingv2
transport_url=rabbit://guest:guest@192.168.29.146:5672/

/etc/neutron/neutron.conf
[DEFAULT]
notify_nova_on_port_status_changes = True
notify_nova_on_port_data_changes = true
transport_url=rabbit://guest:guest@192.168.29.146:5672/
control_exchange = openstack

[oslo_messaging_notifications]
driver = messagingv2
transport_url = rabbit://guest:guest@192.168.29.146:5672/
topics = notifications

Not sure if we are missing something here. Please advice. Thanks in advance.
